# I have a problem when I use the break instruction in python3

Tags: python, cryptography, break

I’m trying to solve a cryptography challenge, in my script I don’t understand why adding a break in my code works and when I remove it I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\achla95\Documents\learn_crypto\favourite_byte.py", line 11, in <module>
    if  'crypto' in cypher_plaintext:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The code :

```py
cypher = bytes.fromhex("73626960647f6b206821204f21254f7d694f7624662065622127234f726927756d")

for i in range(256):
    cypher_plaintext = xor(cypher,i).decode()
    if  'crypto' in cypher_plaintext:
        print(cypher_plaintext)
        break
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Sorry I updated my post.

Comment: probably the problem will solve if you use `b'crypto' in cypher_plaintext`

Comment: cypher_plaintext is not a string apperantly

Comment: @Moein when I add you code I have this error : ```TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes```

Comment: @JakubDóka when I do print(type(cypher_plaintext)) it return : ```<class 'str'>```

Comment: what is xor() function? why you don't use `^` operator?

Comment: @Moein xor() is from a library called pwntool

Comment: can you print the variable itself and show it in comment?

Comment: okay i solved it  just remove .decode() and add if b'crypto' in cypher_text
but thank you guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad you found the solution, but it is best to write it in the answer box for future viewers.

Change:

```
for i in range(256):
    cypher_plaintext = xor(cypher, i).decode()
    if 'crypto' in cypher_plaintext:
        print(cypher_plaintext)
        break
```

To:

```
for i in range(256):
    cypher_plaintext = xor(cypher, i)
    if b'crypto' in cypher_plaintext:
        print(cypher_plaintext)
        break
```